# How do I get to a certain place in my JavaScript object using variables?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a JavaScript object called 'winners' that looks like this:

```
var winners = {
    rock: {
        "scissors": true,
        "paper": false
    }
    paper: {
        "rock": true,
        "scissors": false
    }
    scissors: {
        "rock": false,
        "paper": true
    }
}
```

And I get the users play, as well as the computers play. So to figure out who wins, I need to do something like this:

```
var userPlay = "rock";
var cpuPlay = "paper"; //this would be a function but for now lets simply it and just set it to "paper"
```

So to find the value for computing the winner, I need to go something like this:

```
var winner = winners[userPlay].cpuPlay;
```

But that always returns undefined. Obviously `winners[userPlay].paper` works, but **I'm not sure how to use a variable to get to that final spot. Do I need to get the value of cpuPlay itself and use that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property name is stored in a variable called `cpuPlay`.

```
var cpuPlay = "paper";
```

To access the property you have to use bracket notation:

```
var winner = winners[userPlay][cpuPlay];
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I'll accept as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @DaneelRakow, you're welcome ! Don't forget to accept answer.